# libhoudini/ ARM translation on Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, arm, emulation, code-translation

I have been attempting to install libhoudini onto Android 5.0 on Visual Studio Emulator for Android but I have been unable to get it to work so far.

I've managed to install the ARM translation files (can be found online) on genymotion previously but the performance of Visual Studio Emulator seems to be quite a bit better on my computer.

I'm still getting: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS] after my attempt to install the ARM translation.

Does anyone know how to install libhoudini/ ARM translation on Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you check this: [How-to: Add ARM emulation (Binary Translator aka “libhoudini”) ](http://android-x86.sceners.org/en/?p=536)

Comment: @Teocci These are for older version of android unfortunately. I'm looking to get it working on Android 5.0+ I'll probably just stick with genymotion for now, don't think as many people are using Visual Studio Emulator.